# Strange url "http://www.proxy-listen.de/azenv.php" in my access.log

Tags: php, apache, server, windows-server-2008-r2

There are some strange urls in my access.log
[image]

it's not a virus website

http://www.proxy-listen.de/azenv.php

but i don't know why it can be accessed by the apache in my server? Does it attack my server?

By the way,my server os is WIN2008 and i use php in apache.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Proxy Judge](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/azenvphp-in-error-logs-causing-white-screen-of-death)

Comment: indeed...directly posting a GET with http://www.proxy-listen.de/azenv.php can lead to this access log...

Comment: by any chance u found the solution ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apache returned a 404 error, so you are fine.  It looks like it's an attempt to check for an open proxy - for example, if you have a misconfigured mod_proxy setting it could accidentally make your server an open web proxy.  They failed to find what they were looking for.

Comment: I found a similar trace in a log file.  It came from check.best-proxies.ru.

Comment: Even if it returned 200, that wouldn't necessarily be a bad thing. In that case your server is probably just returning your regular homepage. There is more information and instructions on how to check here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/httpd/ProxyAbuse